# Addon SDK way to make a dialog

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

What is the proper way to use the SDK to make a dialog (which is not anchored to the add-on bar, etc. but shows centered on screen)? It doesn't seem like there is any API for this important capability. I do see `windows/utils` has `open` but I have two problems with that:

1. The dialog opening seems to require "chrome" privs to get it to be centered on the screen (and I'd be expectant of add-on reviewers complaining of chrome privs, and even if not, I'd like to try to stick to the SDK way).
2. While I can get the DOM window reference of the new `window/utils`' `open()` dialog, I'm not sure how to attach a content script so I can respond to user interaction in a way that prompts (and can respond to) privileged behavior ala `postMessage` or `port.emit` (without again, directly working with chrome privs).

Answer (score 5):

Ok, this answer should have been pretty obvious for anyone with a little experience with the SDK. I realized I can just use a [panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel). In my defense, the name "panel" is not as clear as "dialog" in conjuring up this idea, and I am so used to using panels with widgets, that it hadn't occurred to me that I could use it independently!

**Edit**

Unfortunately, as per [Bug 595040](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=595040), these dialogs are not persistent, meaning if the panel loses focus, the "dialog" is gone... So panel looks like it is not a suitable candidate after all... :(

**Edit 2**

I've since moved on and have gotten things working mostly to my satisfaction with `sdk/window/utils` and `openDialog` on whose returned window I add a load listener and then call `tabs.activeTab.on('ready',` and then set `tabs.activeTab.url` to my add-on local HTML file so the `ready` event will get a tab to which I can attach a worker. There is still the problem with chrome privs I suppose, but at least the main communications are using SDK processes.

**Update to Edit 2**:

Code sample provided by request:

```
var data = require('sdk/self').data,
    tabs = require('sdk/tabs');
var win = require('sdk/window/utils').openDialog({
    // No "url" supplied here in this case as we add it below (in order to have a ready listener in place before load which can give us access to the tab worker)
    // For more, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open#Position_and_size_features
    features: Object.keys({
        chrome: true, // Needed for centerscreen per docs
        centerscreen: true, // Doesn't seem to be working for some reason (even though it does work when calling via XPCOM)
        resizable: true,
        scrollbars: true
    }).join() + ',width=850,height=650',
    name: "My window name"
    // parent: 
    // args: 
});
win.addEventListener('load', function () {
    tabs.activeTab.on('ready', function (tab) {
        var worker = tab.attach({
            contentScriptFile: ....
            // ...
        });
        // Use worker.port.on, worker.port.emit, etc...
    });
    tabs.activeTab.url = data.url('myHTMLFile.html');
});
```

Comment: If you have chrome privileges, you can also go straight to the window-watcher service.  This approach avoids some limitations with the other functions: (1) openDialog() limits the URI schemes you can use and (2) open() prevents you from setting the parent window.  Your cool hack to work around the openDialog() limitation won't work for modal windows.

Answer (score 2):

> if the panel loses focus, the "dialog" is gone...

It doesn't get destroyed, just hides, right? If so, depending on why it's getting hidden, you can just call `show()` on it again.

You'd want to make sure it's not being hidden for a good reason before calling show again. If there's a specific situation in which it's losing focus where you don't want it to, create a listener for that situation, then call `if (!panel.isShown) panel.show();`

For example, if it's losing focus because a user clicks outside the box, then that's probably the expected behaviour and nothing should be done. If it's losing focus when the browser/tab loses focus, just register a `tab.on('activate', aboveFunction)`

Comment: I had tried this with the `onHide` event, but perhaps your `activate` check idea could work. For now, I've found another solution (answer updated), so I plan to give the answer to myself as that's the one I've confirmed, but I've updated your answer for giving what sounds like a potential alternative approach (which I might use in the future if revisiting this). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding ",screenX=0,screenY=0" (or any values, the zeroes seem to be meaningless) to the features screen seems to fix centerscreen.